# How can I merge two active record relation with OR condition in rails 3 and return result also an active relation not array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have two associations like surgical_diseases and eye_disease.I want to get the Ored result of the two active relation.But the below code gave me an array.

```
 has_many :surgical_diseases
 has_many :eye_disease

 scope :all_disease ->(name) { joins(:surgical_diseases).where('surgical_diseases.name IN (?)') | joins(:eye_disease).where('eye_disease.name IN (?)') }
```

I have seen `active-record-union` gem but that would only work with active-record 4.I am currently using rails 3.2 so not able to use that.

I also saw that this functionality will come with rails5 with dhh's [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/16052#issuecomment-72718557).But not sure how will I fix this with rail3 now.

I tried my best to make understanding of my question.Please let me know if anything else information is require.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably need to get the ids using find_by_sql and then find those ids to get ActiveRecord::Relation.

```
scope :all_disease ->(name) {  
  ids = YourTable.find_by_sql <<-SQL  
    SELECT your_table.id FROM your_table INNER JOIN surgical_diseases sd ON   sd.your_table_id=your_table.id WHERE sd.name IN (#{name})  
    UNION  
    SELECT your_table.id FROM your_table INNER JOIN eye_diseases ed ON ed.your_table_id=your_table.id WHERE ed.name IN (#{name})  
  SQL  

YourTable.where(id: ids)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, left outer join can help you:

```
scope :all_disease ->(name) { 
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN surgical_diseases ON surgical_diseases.whatever_table_for_your_models_id = whatever_table_for_your_models.id')
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN eye_diseases ON eye_diseases.whatever_table_for_your_models_id = .whatever_table_for_your_models.id')
  .where('surgical_diseases.name IN (?) OR eye_diseases.name IN (?)', name)
```

Comment: It would not work as it will give the AND results of first `LEFT JOIN` and second `LEFT JOIN`.Whereas I need OR result of the two joins.